# Uploading zip file to PHP upload site doesn't work, but works for mac

Tags: php, html, upload

I have two of the exact same files. Test.zip, both the same size. This file was created on my mac, and works with my upload script just fine. I made a second Test.zip on my Windows machine and tried uploading, nothing.

Why is this?

All file types are listed correctly in the index and upload, and there is no file size. I can upload zip files from my mac, not my XP machine. I can upload all other formats besides rar/zip from windows.

index.html types

```
   acceptedTypes = {
      'image/png': true,
      'image/jpeg': true,
      'image/gif': true,
      'application/x-rar-compressed': true,
      'application/zip': true,
      'application/octet-stream': true
    },
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
            }
        #holder {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            border: 10px dashed #ccc;
            min-height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            }
        #holder.hover {
            border-color: #0c0;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="holder"></div>
    <p id="upload" class="hidden"><label>Drag &amp; drop not supported, but you can still upload via this input field:<br><input type="file"></label></p>
    <p id="filereader">File API &amp; FileReader API not supported</p>
    <p id="formdata">XHR2's FormData is not supported</p>
    <p id="progress">XHR2's upload progress isn't supported</p>
    <p>Upload progress: <progress id="uploadprogress" min="0" max="100" value="0">0</progress></p>

<script>
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
    tests = {
      filereader: typeof FileReader != 'undefined',
      dnd: 'draggable' in document.createElement('span'),
      formdata: !!window.FormData,
      progress: "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest
    }, 
    support = {
      filereader: document.getElementById('filereader'),
      formdata: document.getElementById('formdata'),
      progress: document.getElementById('progress')
    },
    acceptedTypes = {
      'image/png': true,
      'image/jpeg': true,
      'image/gif': true,
      'application/x-rar-compressed': true,
      'application/zip': true,
      'application/octet-stream': true
    },
    progress = document.getElementById('uploadprogress'),
    fileupload = document.getElementById('upload');

"filereader formdata progress".split(' ').forEach(function (api) {
  if (tests[api] === false) {
    support[api].className = 'fail';
  } else {
    // FFS. I could have done el.hidden = true, but IE doesn't support
    // hidden, so I tried to create a polyfill that would extend the
    // Element.prototype, but then IE10 doesn't even give me access
    // to the Element object. Brilliant.
    support[api].className = 'hidden';
  }
});

function previewfile(file) {
  if (tests.filereader === true && acceptedTypes[file.type] === true) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = event.target.result;
      image.width = 250; // a fake resize
      holder.appendChild(image);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }  else {
    holder.innerHTML += '<p>Uploaded ' + file.name + ' ' + (file.size ? (file.size/1024|0) + 'K' : '');
    console.log(file);
  }
}

function readfiles(files) {
    debugger;
    var formData = tests.formdata ? new FormData() : null;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (tests.formdata) formData.append('file', files[i]);
      previewfile(files[i]);
    }

    // now post a new XHR request
    if (tests.formdata) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');
      xhr.onload = function() {
        progress.value = progress.innerHTML = 100;
      };

      if (tests.progress) {
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
          if (event.lengthComputable) {
            var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
            progress.value = progress.innerHTML = complete;
          }
        }
      }

      xhr.send(formData);
    }
}

if (tests.dnd) { 
  holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
  holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
  holder.ondrop = function (e) {
    this.className = '';
    e.preventDefault();
    readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  }
} else {
  fileupload.className = 'hidden';
  fileupload.querySelector('input').onchange = function () {
    readfiles(this.files);
  };
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "rar", "zip");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-rar-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))

&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: What's the size of file? Did you try to upload really small files?

Comment: Tried everything. Nothing above like 3mb uploads. It had a file limit, which I upped to 200000000 or something ridiculous, around 200mb, and nothing above 5mb on either platform uploaded. I'll try application/octet since I've been using octet-stream, but its weird because other files from Windows XP upload, just not zips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value of `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` when uploading the Windows compressed ZIP?  Could be a mimetype issue. Microsoft tends to use `application/octet` when the rest of the sane world uses `application/octet-stream`.

In general, it’s best to do a dump of variables posted to debug things like this.  Would recommend placing this near the top of your `upload.php` to see what’s actually being passed:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Got it working, just added a bunch of extra mime types hahaha. http://filext.com/file-extension/ZIP